# Mongoid: references_in in a model with embed content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have got an annoying problem with my models here:

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :subject
  field :text
  field :sender_deleted, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :recipient_deleted, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :read_at#, :type => DateTime

  referenced_in :sender, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :snt_msg
  referenced_in :recipient, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :rcvd_msg

  embeds_many :replies, :class_name => "Message"
  embedded_in :message, :inverse_of => :replies
end
```

and this structure for User:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :username, type: String
  field :password_hash, type: String
  field :password_salt, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :role, type: Boolean, default: -> {false}

  references_many :snt_msg, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :sender
  references_many :rcvd_msg, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :recipient
end
```

When I want to load the page with the associated form in there, I get this error:

> undefined method `referenced_in' for Message:Class

Why does this happen?

- MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
- ruby 2.0.0p247
- rails 4.0.0

Comment: no one knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get and "undefined method" error, but you should know that it is not possible in mongoid to reference an embedded document.

Try replacing your `embeds_many`/`embedded_in` by references.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i should use embed. there is any way else to have embed and relation together?

Comment: You should really consider why you "should" use embed. Remember that a MongoDB document's maximum size is 16 MB, including all embedded documents. In your case, a mail sent to many persons that generates many replies could quickly exceed that limit.

Comment: would be better design for that?